# Can't Add LINQ to SQL classes to projects in VS2010

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

I just ran into something in Visual Studio 2010 RC that wasn't previously happening (like, yesterday).  No software changes here, but I did run into some muck yesterday when compiling that required a reboot.

I am unable to add LINQ to SQL classes to any project through the add dialog. I have created ASP.NET web sites, ASP.NET MVC projects - both of these as 'templated' and as 'empty' - and there appear to be no templates installed or available.

[alt text http://bandofgeeks.net/blogimages/code/notemplate.png](http://bandofgeeks.net/blogimages/code/notemplate.png)

I have made sure that the project targets the 4.0 Framework.  I can easily add a new database and the ADO.NET entity framework templates are there.

As a workaround I can copy a DBML file to my project, delete all tables and sprocs, update the connection string and use the leftover shell (the designer works fine like this), but it's a pain.

Has anyone else had their templates drop?  Figured out how to reinstall them?

Comment: do you find the Linq-to-SQL classes if you type "LINQ" into the "Search installed templates" box at the top right??

Comment: no, nothing there. I've also tried the online templates and nothing there.  I've even backed out or changed my scope and tried 'code', 'Visual C#', 'Data' and 'Web' to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In previous versions of Visual Studio, you were able to "reset" the default template registration using this command line switch when launching VS:

```
devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
```

I haven't tried it with Visual Studio 2010 yet - but it might be worth a try! It's definitely available - see the [MSDN docs on VS 2005 command line switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks marc, worked a treat.  the switch isn't documented in the /? command line prompt, but this worked just the same.

cheers,
-jc