# Visual Studio 2010 MVC Project type Disappeared

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, project-template

I have been working with visual studio 2010 Premium RTM for over a month. When I installed it I had a fresh install of windows. (No betas or previous versions of VS)

I have been creating new ASP.NET MVC2 C# projects since I installed it.  I went to create a new mvc project today and I don't have that as an option anymore. I went in under the new project section not the new website section.  I don't see it listed under C# or VB.

Is there a way to get that back without reinstalling visual studio?

Comment: Are you sure you still have .net 3.5 selected as the target framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with Linq to SQL templates. Try the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562768/cant-add-linq-to-sql-classes-to-projects-in-vs2010/2563025#2563025) on this other stack overflow question.

The solution was to run

> devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates

to reinstall the templates. It worked for me when I had missing templates in Visual Studio 2010.